# jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

In this simplistic example:

```
var myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log($(obj));
}
```

I am using the $.  If I use:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var myObj = {X:1};
myFunction(myObj);
```

Then the $ is no longer valid.

But if I wrap myFunction inside of

```
jQuery(function($) {
var myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log($(obj));
}
});
```

Then it's no longer found.  myFunction is in a separate script, so I can't wrap everything in one gigantic jQuery(function($) {}.

Comment: All true. What's your question?

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` with `()`!

Comment: Please notice that you can always use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: We still don't know what the actual question is. So far it's just a bunch of moaning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
( function($) {
  window.myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log($(obj));
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Seperate file:

```
myFunction({X:1});
```

The difference is that your code is executed immediately not after the dom is ready and you are placing the function in the global context (window.) so it will be available everywhere.

I don't know what it is your doing, but in this case you may find a JQuery plugin suits you better:

```
( function($) {
  $.fn.myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log(this);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Seperate file:

```
jQuery({X:1}).myFunction();
```

Of course, $( {X:1} ) might do strange things with JQuery - I've never tried it before!

Comment: I always have to say to myself "Don't forget to put your 'pa' in separate".

Comment: I like this solution best.  It wraps my all my code into a function to keep my 'global' variables local to that script, and it exposes myFunction to other script tags.

Comment: @Sprog This solution is OK, but avoid polluting the window namespace with many functions.  If you have more than one function that you want to be available everywhere, think about creating your own namespace.

Comment: A jQuery plugin is another good way to encapsulate your functions, but I think the example given is confusing, since {X:1} is not a selector.  You should able to pass your obj to myFunction inside jQuery:  i.e: jQuery().myFunction({X:1}).

Comment: @mwolfetech I couldn't agree more, generally I would always avoid adding to the global namespace, however this question appeared to request it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just change your function to do this:

```
var myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log(jQuery(obj));
}
```

You can also do:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

var myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log($j(obj));
}
```

Then you can use $j everywhere you were using just $.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is not to wrap `myFunction()` but its contents.

```
var myFunction = function(obj) {
    (function( $ ) {
        console.log($(obj));
    })( jQuery );
};
```

Comment: But this is completely and utterly redundant.

Comment: @Tomalak: In this simple case yes, but I assume the actual function is much more complex :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFunction = function(obj) {
    console.log(jQuery(obj));
}
```

`noConflict` just means you can't use `$`, which is a shorthand for `jQuery`. You don't need to wrap everything in an onLoad handler (your final example) just because you went in `noConflict` mode.

Use whatever means you like to transform your existing `$` into `jQuery`. Options include:

- search and replace in your text editor;
- context-wrapping functions around your individual code sections.

Comment: Yeah I guess I could use the 'jQuery' keyword wherever I'm using a $.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: That is the correct thing to do. That is how to modify your code when using noConflict mode.

Answer (score 1):

don't use var, because it will be a local variable of the ready() function. use window.myFunction, define myFunction directly,  or create the var outside .ready().

Comment: I've just gotten into the habit of using var.  This is a good piece of advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could namespace your external scripts:

```
var WEB = function ($) {
  return {
      myFunction: function(obj) {
        console.log($(obj));
      }

      // can add more properties / functions here

  };
}(jQuery);
```

Then your main script could look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var myObj = {X:1};
  WEB.myFunction(myObj);
});
```

Then you do not need to change the $ to jQuery in all external code, and the main script remains small.  This works well if you want to modularize your code.  It also keeps you from polluting the global namespace with many functions that you want to access across scripts--all your code can be organized under the WEB namespace.  You are only adding a single var (WEB) to the global namespace.

You can also use variations of this pattern to hide information about your implementation.  See: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/  (Don't miss the comment by Caridy Patiño)

Comment: Oh I see.  So instead of calling myFunction, I would call myNamespace.myFunction.  Hmmmm.  This sounds like the ultimate solution.  I'll probably start using this in future projects.